# Template variable in sfinae context

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Please consider this first snippet of code, in which a basic SFINAE trigger is used to discriminate whether a type is a random access iterator:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_random_access_iterator : public std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_random_access_iterator<T, 
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>
    >>
    : public std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_random_access_iterator_v = is_random_access_iterator<T>::value;
```

This code compiles and works just as expected. Now, consider this second snippet, where I substituted a template variable to the `enable_if` condition, without changing its definition at all:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_random_access_iterator_tag = 
    std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_random_access_iterator : public std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_random_access_iterator<T, 
    std::enable_if_t<
        //std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>
        has_random_access_iterator_tag<T>
    >>
    : public std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_random_access_iterator_v = is_random_access_iterator<T>::value;
```

SFINAE doesn't work anymore and the compiler (tested with gcc 8 and clang 7) complains about `std::iterator_traits` not existing whenever I supply a type it isn't specialized for.

Here's a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_random_access_iterator_tag = 
    std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_random_access_iterator : public std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_random_access_iterator<T, 
    std::enable_if_t<
        //std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>
        has_random_access_iterator_tag<T>
    >>
    : public std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_random_access_iterator_v = is_random_access_iterator<T>::value;

int main() {
    std::cout   << std::boolalpha << "Is random access iterator:\n"
                << "- int:   " << is_random_access_iterator_v<int> << '\n'
                << "- int*:  " << is_random_access_iterator_v<int*> << '\n'
                << "- v::it: " << is_random_access_iterator_v<std::vector<int>::iterator> << '\n';
}
```

And the output:

> prog.cc:8:54: error: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'std::__1::iterator_traits'
>       std::is_same_v::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>;
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> prog.cc:17:9: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'has_random_access_iterator_tag' requested here
>           has_random_access_iterator_tag
>           ^
>
> prog.cc:22:46: note: during template argument deduction for class template partial specialization 'is_random_access_iterator > >' [with T = int]
>   constexpr bool is_random_access_iterator_v = is_random_access_iterator::value;
>                                                ^
>
> prog.cc:22:46: note: in instantiation of template class 'is_random_access_iterator' requested here
>   prog.cc:26:35: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'is_random_access_iterator_v' requested here
>                   << "- int:   " << is_random_access_iterator_v << '\n'
>                                     ^
>   1 error generated.

Can anyone explain me why? I'm frustrated by this because it feels very natural to use a template constant to make template programming more compact and readable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_random_access_iterator_tag = 
    std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>;
```

Moves

```
std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>
```

out of a SFINAE context and puts it into just compiled code.  SFINAE kicks when when substituting the deduced types for a template parameter fails durring overload resolution.  Since

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_random_access_iterator_tag = 
    std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>;
```

only has `T` as a template parameter there is no failure when you try and instantiate a  `has_random_access_iterator_tag<T>`.  Since there is no failure then

```
std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>;
```

gets compiled and if `T` is not valid for that expression then you get an error.

If you move the expression back into the template parameter then when the compiler deduces `T` it will use it to deduce

```
std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>;
```

and if that fails then it wont be an error since it happened durring the deduction of the template parameters.  So if we have

```
template <typename T, bool Val = std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>>
constexpr bool has_random_access_iterator_tag = Val;
```

then if `std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category` is invalid the whole template is considered invalid and ignored.

Comment: could you elaborate please? Why should the template variable always be compiled, since it's only used in the context of one specialization? I don't understand the link with its role as an initializer either.

Comment: It's really clear now, even if I feel like there should be a "continuity-of-context principle": an error in an instantiation called from sfinae context should have a kind of diplomatic immunity.