# Different SFINAE behavior of `std::tuple_size_v` on different compilers

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider this code:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename = void> struct is_tuple_like : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_tuple_like<T, decltype(std::tuple_size_v<T>, void())> : std::true_type {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_tuple_like<std::string>::value << '\n';
}
```

<kbd>[Run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMS6dSAB1QLC62nqGJmZePn50NnaORi5unB5KKmp0DATMxASBxqbmiZiq/qnpBJEOzq7uimkZWcG51SW2ZTEV8QCUiqgGxMgcAORSAMy2yIZYANTigzoEBp7sU9jiAAwAgkMjY5iT0wQAnp6YAPoExMyECosr65LDtKMGE1M66gqnmMxGV2vXBJhG82Yfx2MwOWk%2B2wAKqRxvtDrQITsACLjABuqDw6EW4zexAMqnGeAUJzm7COrDwAGttiAcQR0CAQFQ2EoTmDJgB2WQcpFTWRrP4A4TA55w8FGKHY3H4giE4mzebHCnU57Q8ZYUZiiBvBkgBVk3wAL2OqNVixh6MxEDabWxtJ1jNOBmOYs53N5g356zWtllRnOtGt13EXOu43DdN1aAMsuezzlJMV5KpmGeDpAuNswEWjNRbGdIPjYAGAFYdLRi3zgzzrn0OqwQH0S31SKY%2BssW6hGzo5HIcV0etshpwWwRGx2baRKWYAGwAOkGtxLt24AA4SzOOdwOUJG9wW22O6Qu30WwoQMtSGP23XSHBYDAoI%2BIEg0AC8OwyBQIG/PB%2BKsAnDLOYVAfn8xDnhATjji2Ti2OkeyNiOpBvhK9AAPK0KwiE3qQWD%2BqI7AwXheDEPkaiopg564ZgAAe%2BQxv0yG%2BsoxEUk4ZzEHsehYMRpx4EYSG3jQ9BMGwHA8PwITCKIKC9jIQh4E456QB0qCeMktDUQAtDqUxIhIMhyJIyzjNpADqbCsGZ5l0aczBmYc6AiGoyDaa4xAkAoZ7KOR/iaNotQ5B4lilNEsSCN4viaUFZgeFF4S0GF5RxIovkFCkDSxZICTpZpRQZMlLSpW8xTZQkDRFRFnAdAoA69Fw9aNs2rbESetGrjO2kztw4zAMgyDjEBc6SOMEC4IQJCTLcHjjHo76ftNi5tHN8nSKOMGTggHxYG41pTiAJaXg2fT7qQglHa1uEnmeF5Xptd7PkgXQEJ4MbkJQv7/m45iYPgRCpSJjAsERQGkAA7mcnhCU1TYHm1jZDKN4OEAg4wdV1PV9QNQ3LCNG03ltO0VPtJ1nRdl6Hp2ja3Ze14Th006XSdgzw9dNP3YTj3wPeiAoKgC2uB9P4C3%2Bn4oDJgFAR4oGsOBkHQbhcEIlxQkoQLaEEJh2HEfhIjAERuH4GRBSUdRR50QxfxqyxJ1HuxnHcRg/RHvxgl9COHRA2JoO8AIgxCPrclGQp7Eqft6maTpemDAZa0mTZVk2XZZyOX9Ll4G5HleT5ST%2BRAlixSF2hVa0oTRf4Rfl4lpclXlhRZfo2SCHkGW0AVjRRClLeN0EpgVcUteNZ03QNTVu5w1dR7tZ13W9aM%2BtDZwc545wY0TQDS2zfNYuuEtgwrT2IfrZzDOkNtzC7ZQjOHcde4thTU/U6eih3fTt68y%2BIAvW9BDC194sA5/UmoDOgwNxJcEvJDZg0MPa3hOi1Kmx5Ea3EGOMFGBA0YYznuMBeogl4rznMhd%2BRNL4k1huTW%2BT9kEv3PHTTaN9maNlZtQm6p86w324PObgABOHh3BBg8MGIMZcm5JInUkA/SBlMEYvxIdzB8PNXyi2%2Bv/FR4tUTIE8J4I4qJOA8KOJIVcRxaI9VILLeWlBFZHmVghNWqEtBaywjhI8etCIuxbMbPyZtiKW2QIxG29BWK4QdghHiHirzEAEjDcxYCfYST9oISWwdZChyUuHNSGl/DUQAPQOkMqk6QwoqIEFzn5DQBdApN2CMXawTRwplwSjFap/dq6aSHrlPOmUyotJbvXbphV6ndwHjUXpIzO7NGqrVeqElYaINkaY3qRgFCaLRPokaq517/SmsOGEO9vpb0PmtAmZ8L5X32kzO%2Bp0pGXSQWwuh7COif2ejGX%2BajBapWAQDQQ3sQYSSgVDGJCC2bTxQYMNeGCsFY2WasvRPCNknI4efYme0KE3JkezWhb8GEHUkByIhHIOTLEGByTgHIeHLBLKuTgJYdwsxBc/RFk4JEMpoUyjolEIL%2BW4EAA%3D%3D)</kbd>

On GCC 10.2 and MSVC 19.28 it causes a hard error, along the lines of:

```
error: incomplete type 'std::tuple_size<...>' used in nested name specifier
```

On Clang 11.0.1, on the other hand, it compiles and prints `1`, with both libstdc++ and libc++.

Which compiler is correct here?

Notice that Clang prints `1` and not `0`, meaning it doesn't treat `std::tuple_size<std::string>::value` (the initializer of `tuple_size_v`) as a soft error, but instead chooses to disregard it completely!

Which makes sense in a way, since if `tuple_size_v` is defined as `template <typename T> inline constexpr size_t tuple_size_v = ...`, the type `decltype(tuple_size_v<...>)` doesn't depend on the template parameter, and is always `size_t`.

I guess the question boils down to whether the initializer of `tuple_size_v` is required to be instantiated here, even though it's not strictly necessary.

---

I know that I can fix it by replacing `std::tuple_size_v<...>` with `std::tuple_size<...>::value`, then it prints `0` on all three compilers.

Comment: I think this question will be more juicy if you incorporate some of what we discussed under my deleted answer. To `size_t` or not to `size_t` can be made more explicit.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Agree, edited to add some juice.

Comment: It seems [GCC treats function templates and variable templates differently](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WMa8YP). I bet it's a GCC (and MSVC) bug.

Comment: Also, if we [remove the `void` part](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T7Po1d), Clang will output 0. It's weird.

Comment: [CWG2222](http://wg21.link/cwg2222)?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Hmm, though it doesn't say anything about variable templates.

Comment: @xskxzr Not really weird, because the `decltype(...)` is now not `void`, so the specialization doesn't match and the primary template is selected.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Note I changed the default template argument to `std::size_t`.

Comment: Possible duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858074/template-variable-in-sfinae-context  - but I have no idea if the answer meets your expectaions...

Answer (score 7):

I think Clang has this right.

The rule from [[temp.inst]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#7) is:

> Unless a variable template specialization is a declared specialization, the variable template specialization is implicitly instantiated when it is referenced in a context that requires a variable definition to exist or if the existence of the definition affects the semantics of the program.

This program doesn't require the *definition* of `std::tuple_size_v<std::string>`, only the declaration. And the declaration:

```cpp
template <typename T>
inline constexpr size_t tuple_size_v = tuple_size<T>::value;
```

Is enough to evaluate the expression in the partial specialization. `decltype(std::tuple_size_v<T>, void())` doesn't depend on the value here at all, for any `size_t`, that's a valid expression of type `void`.

Were we dealing with a function template instead of a variable template:

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr size_t tuple_size_v() { return tuple_size<T>::value; }
```

It's perhaps more clear that we don't need the definition, just the declaration, and both gcc and msvc accept this alternate formulation (indeed, gcc even warns on it being pointless): [example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nszT3h).

Later, in [[temp.inst]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#8), we have:

> The existence of a definition of a variable or function is considered to affect the semantics of the program if the variable or function is needed for constant evaluation by an expression ([expr.const]), even if constant evaluation of the expression is not required or if constant expression evaluation does not use the definition.

But that is not the case here: we don't need the variable for constant evaluation.

Comment: Interesting. In [this example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T7Po1d) (provided by xskxzr in the comments) Clangs fails to do the same thing.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah that's the same kind of thing - you only need `decltype(tuple_size_v<T>)` and you know that's `size_t` without having to know the value of it.

Comment: There's one thing I'm not sure about: does the standard even have a concept of instatiating variable template declarations separately from their defintions? I can find things about "instantiating function declarations", but nothing about variable declarations.